# Volley handle onErrorResponse

Tags: android, android-volley

I am getting status `400` and server giving some response , where i can get that message

```
 @Override
 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
       NetworkResponse errorRes = error.networkResponse;
       Log.d(TAG, errorRes.statusCode+"");
 }
```

how I can get message  which server giving me . basically apart from 200 volley will give `errorresponse`. Now where can I data which I am getting?

`errorRes.data` also giving wrong info.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@Override
 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

       NetworkResponse errorRes = error.networkResponse;
       String stringData = "";
       if(errorRes != null && errorRes.data != null){
            stringData = new String(errorRes.data,"UTF-8");
       }
       Log.e("Error",stringData)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the error message if available by overriding `parseNetworkError` as the following:

```
            @Override
            protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
                String json;
                if (volleyError.networkResponse != null && volleyError.networkResponse.data != null) {
                    try {
                        json = new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data,
                                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(volleyError.networkResponse.headers));
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        return new VolleyError(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    return new VolleyError(json);
                }
                return volleyError;
            }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to hit api on server, it means OnResponse will be called. 
OnErrorResponse is called when some volley error such as no internet connection or if URL is invalid occur.

If you want to know what message comes from server, parse the response you get in OnResponse.

Comment: thing is on response is call when i am doing proper request that time server gives statuscode 200 but if i pass wrong params then it gives 400 and it goes to onErrorResponse

Comment: If params are wrong, that response comes from server side. 
If you are getting response in ErrorResponse, it means there is some other error either internet connectivity or the way you are trying to hit api.

Comment: then where i can get response when status code is not 200 ?

Comment: ErrorResponse. 
because if api was hit successfully , it means you were able to communicate to your server. 

If you get  status 400, it means you were not able to hit api on server. 

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html