# How to get JSON error response in Volley onErrorResponse

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an API call with below details

> URL: http://pankajservers.in/api/v1/AuthenticateUser with Input params
>   below
>
> EmailAddress and Password

if I type wrong credentials, I get below JSON response with Status Code : 403

```
{"Status":false,"Message":"Invalid Credentials. 5 attempts left.","Data":null}
```

**Below is the Error Response Code.**

```
new Response.ErrorListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
    {
        if (null != error.networkResponse)
        {
            Log.d(TAG + ": ", "Error Response code: " + error.networkResponse.statusCode);
        }
    }
});
```

Is there any way to get JSON response in this code block?

I tried this post: [Volley handle onErrorResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393788/volley-handle-onerrorresponse)

But it seems it never execute parseNetworkError

Comment: u have to create custom request...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To print the Error on that block you just need to obtain the Response bytes:

```
 NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
 if (networkResponse != null && networkResponse.data != null) {
       String jsonError = new String(networkResponse.data);
       // Print Error!
 }
```

Comment: In the event that the actual message you need is nested in a JSON object, instantiating a new JSON object that accepts the jsonError above will allow you to access the JSON object message...

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom request like this:

```
public class BaseRequest extends Request {
    private static final String TAG = BaseRequest.class.getSimpleName();
    private final Gson gson = new Gson();


    private final Response.Listener listener;

    public BaseRequest(String url, Response.Listener responseListener, Response.ErrorListener listener) {
        super(Request.Method.GET, url, listener);
        Log.e(TAG, "Requesting url : " + url);
        this.listener = responseListener;
    }
    public BaseRequest(int method, String url, Response.Listener responseListener, Response.ErrorListener listener) {
        super(method, url, listener);
        Log.e(TAG, "Requesting url : " + url);
        this.listener = responseListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

        try {
            String json = null;
            json = new String(
                    response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            JSONObject result = new JSONObject(json);

            if (!result.getBoolean("Status"))
                return Response.success(
                        result.get("Data"),
                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            else
                return Response.error(new VolleyError(result.getString("Message")));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));

        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {

            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
        return volleyError;
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(Object response) {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }


}
```

and make request:

```
BaseRequest baseRequest = new BaseRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Object response) {


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error : " + error.getMessage());


            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

               //Your parameters
                return params;
            }
        };

queue.add(baseRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast an error response to a Json Object

```
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    JsonObjectRequest JO = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,"URL String Here",jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        //Your Logic

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        try {

        JSONObject JO = new JSONObject(error.toString());

        }catch (JSONException e){

        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
    });
```