# Get error returning server with Volley

Tags: java, android, rest, android-volley

I am making an application in which I consume an external service and for this, I am using Volley library of Google. I am trying to process the error with the structure:

```
{
 "message": "invalid public_key",
 "error": "not_found",
 "status": 404,
 "cause": [
    {
    "code": "1001",
    "description": "public_key not found"
    }
  ]
}
```

but Volley directly calls the onErrorResponse method (VolleyError error) returning a generic error, in this case 404. How do I proceed to get that structure and get the data I need?

Service schema code:

```
mProgress = UIComponents.showProgressDialog(this);
Request<?> requestCreditCard = RequestFactory.getCreditCard(this,
        getString(R.string.base_url),
        getString(R.string.payment_methods_url),
        getString(R.string.public_key),
        new OkInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onOkResponse(JSONArray response) throws JSONException {
                loadCreditCards(response);
            }
        },
        new ErrorInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onShowErrorResponse() {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.without_results, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void doErrorHandler() {
                UIComponents.hideProgressDialog(mProgress);
            }


        });
RequestNetworkCache.getmQueue().add(requestCreditCard);


  public class BaseRequestApi extends JsonArrayRequest{

  public BaseRequestApi(Context context, String url, OkInterface 
  okInterface,
                  ErrorInterface errorInterface) {

   super(Method.GET, url, null, new BaseResponseApi(context,errorInterface, 
   okInterface), new BaseErrorApi(context,errorInterface));

   configRequest(context);
  }

    private void configRequest(Object cancelTag) {
     this.setTag(cancelTag);
     this.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        0,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.D`enter code here`EFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    }
  }


@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    errorDelegate.onShowErrorResponse();
    if(error instanceof TimeoutError)
        Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.time_out_error, 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(error instanceof NetworkError)
        Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.network_error, 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(error instanceof NoConnectionError)
        Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.no_connection_error, 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(error instanceof ServerError)
        Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.server_error, 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}




  @Override
  public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
   if( response.length() > 0 ) {
      try {
         okDelegate.onOkResponse(response);

      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(mContext, 
        mContext.getString(R.string.unexpected_error), 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        errorDelegate.doErrorHandler();
      }
  }else {
    errorDelegate.onShowErrorResponse();
    errorDelegate.doErrorHandler();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42039254/5217712).

Comment: @Enzokie it works !, Thanks!